# $_REQUEST works on one page but not another

Tags: php, mysql, request

Okay folks my question is pretty basic.

Here are the basics.

My site is on GoDaddy shared hosting.

I have a pagination script that works perfect on one page.

http://subdomain.mysite.com/category.php

In a different part of the site;

http://www.mysite.com/admin/page.php

I get an error with this line:

`$page= $_REQUEST['page'];`

I don't put up the rest of the script, because it is identical on both pages with the exception of the query variables.

On the second page I get an `Notice: Undefined index: page ....` error.

What am I missing?

Is there are work around?

Comment: What do you expect `$_REQUEST` to contain?

Comment: What is the problem? PHP tells you that there is no array member called `page` in $_REQUEST. That is true, there never is, _read the documentation_. Why should it suddenly appear? What do you expect to be contained in `$_REQUEST['page']` ?

Comment: You missed the code here.

Comment: to avoid the error you need to check the value $page= isset($_REQUEST['page']) ? $_REQUEST['page'] : 1;

Comment: Thanks Haim Evgi... That worked like a charm.....

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to get a param you are not passing to the server.

I guess you pass your pagination params in the query, but this is failing on your "page 1" where you still don't pass anything.

Try with:

```
$page = 1;
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) {
    $page = (int)$_REQUEST['page'];
}
```